# How to use find() method on nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, find

In this example you can see that find method works fine in this array:

```js
var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];


console.log(inventory.find(fruit => fruit.name === 'cherries')); 
// { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }
```

Once I add one more level and trying to find item in it it just dont find it, it shows undefined:

```js
var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5, type: [
       {name: 'rainier', quantity: 3},
       {name: 'bing', quantity: 2}
     ]}
];


console.log(inventory.find(fruit => fruit.name === 'bing')); 
// undefined
// should be: { name: 'bing', quantity: 2 }
```

So I guess there is some other way to do this, but i dont know it and cant find nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't allowing for the optional `type` array. Assuming you want to do a depth-first search, you'd make your callback a named function and use it recursively, see comments:

```js
var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5, type: [
       {name: 'rainier', quantity: 3},
       {name: 'bing', quantity: 2}
    ]}
];

// Define the function
function find(array, name) {
    // Loop the entries at this level
    for (const entry of array) {
        // If we found it, return it
        if (entry.name === name) {
            return entry;
        }
        // If not but there's a type array, recursively search it
        if (Array.isArray(entry.type)) {
            const found = find(entry.type, name);
            if (found) {
                // Recursive search found it, return it
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    // If execution falls off the end, it's effectively `return undefined;`
}
console.log(find(inventory, 'bing'));
```

Comment: Good, thanks. I checked and it works even if array is more deeper. Thanks.

Comment: @EdgarsŠusts - No worries! Yes, that's where the recursion comes in handy. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`inventory.find` will only find element of array with given conditions in the `inventory` and because `{name: 'bing', quantity: 2}` is not present in `inventory` so it will return `undefined`
.You can do that using **recursion**

```js
var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5, type: [
       {name: 'rainier', quantity: 3},
       {name: 'bing', quantity: 2}
     ]}
];

function findFruitWithName(arr,name){
  let x = arr.find(fruit => fruit.name === name);
  if(x === undefined){
    for(let fruit of arr){
      if(fruit.type) {
        let y = findFruitWithName(fruit.type,name);
        if(y !== undefined) return y
      }
    }
  }
  else return x;
}


console.log(findFruitWithName(inventory,'bing'))
// undefined
// should be: { name: 'bing', quantity: 2 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that `find` only looks at the elements in the array and doesn't look in the nested ones, so you have to create your own.

You could loop over all the items in the `inventory` and collect all the elements in the potential `type` arrays and continue to loop over them until you find an item with the desired `name`, or return `undefined` if you check all items and you don't find a match.

**Example**

```js
const inventory = [
  { name: "apples", quantity: 2 },
  { name: "bananas", quantity: 0 },
  {
    name: "cherries",
    quantity: 5,
    type: [{ name: "rainier", quantity: 3 }, { name: "bing", quantity: 2 }]
  }
];

function findItem(inventory, name) {
  let items = [...inventory];
  let item;

  while (items.length !== 0) {
    item = items.pop();
    if (item.name === name) {
      return item;
    } else if (item.type) {
      items.push(...item.type);
    }
  }

  return undefined;
}

console.log(findItem(inventory, "bing"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5, type: [
       {name: 'rainier', quantity: 3},
       {name: 'bing', quantity: 2}
     ]}
];
var name = 'bing'
var result = inventory.find((fruit) => {
  if(fruit.name === name) return true
  if(fruit.type) return fruit.type.find(type=>type.name===name) 
  return false
})
console.log(result)
```

**UPDATE:**
if you want it to make it recursive you can try

function find(name, inventory) {

```
 return inventory.find((fruit) => {
  if(fruit.name === name) return true
  if(fruit.type) return find(name, fruit.type)
  return false
}) 
}
console.log(find(name,inventory))
```